# 'mypy' failure due to circular dependency

Tags: python, mypy, python-typing

I am writing some python code with type hinting and am facing a circular dependency problem with mypy.

```
#a/interface.py
from typing import TYPE_CHECKING
  
if TYPE_CHECKING:
    from b import B

class A:
    def f(self) -> 'B':
        pass

#a/__init__.py
from .interface import *

#b/interface.py
from typing import TYPE_CHECKING
  
if TYPE_CHECKING:
    from a import A

class B:
    def f(self) -> 'A':
        pass

#b/__init__.py
from .interface import *
```

Now if I run the command *MYPYPATH=$PWD mypy a.py*, I get the following error

> b/interface.py:3: error: Module 'a' has no attribute 'A'
>
> a/interface.py:3: error: Module 'b' has no attribute 'B'

How can I fix this ?

Comment: `class b` in b.py is lowercase, but you're importing it as uppercase.

Comment: You are using `'A'` rather than `A` for the annotation of `b.f`; are you sure you *need* the `from a import A`?

Comment: @SuperStormer, you are right. That is a typo. The error goes away if I fix that. However, I tried to put together this simplified example to illustrate a problem I was having and I over-simplified. I'll try to revise my question.

Comment: @SuperStormer, I have revised my question.

Comment: Mypy does not understand `*` imports.

Comment: Your example works fine here. You don't need to play with MYPYPATH or anything, just run `mypy a b` and it's all good.

Comment: Please be aware that your example is still inconsistent. The question lists the files ``a/interface.py`` and ``a/__init__.py`` but checks ``MYPYPATH=$PWD mypy a.py``.